# What has changed with webview.loadURL between Android 4.2.2 and 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an app that loads part of a website containing some javascript  based on a cars license plate. The page is shown as expected on a Samsung Galaxy s4 with Android 4.2.2 but not with 4.4.2 When I test the app with Android 4.4.2 what is displayed is the `document.body.style.minWidth` i.e. the webview displays the text: 300px

I've wasted way to much time staring like a blind man so any hints or help is more than welcome!

The code is this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    reg = getIntent().getStringExtra("reg");

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setTypeface(tf);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Motorregister - (DMR)");

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        private ProgressDialog pd;
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (count==1) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('regnr').checked=true;"
                        +"document.getElementById('soegeord').value='"+reg+"';"
                        +"document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();"
                        +"DMR.WaitForLoad.on();");
            } else if (count>=2) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.innerHTML " +
                        "= '<div class=\"tabNav\">'+document.getElementsByClassName('tabNav')[0].innerHTML+'</div>';" +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('h-tab-content')[0].style.width='320px';" +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('h-tab-btns')[0].style.width='320px';" +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('h-tab-btns')[0].style.height='45px';" +
                        "document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display='inline';" +
                        "document.head.appendChild='<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\">';" +
                        "document.body.style.minWidth ='300px';");
                if (pd!=null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (pd==null || !pd.isShowing()) {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(SkatActivity.this, ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
                pd.setTitle("ebb.dk");
                pd.setMessage("Vent venligst...");
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                pd.show();
            }

            count++;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
    wv.loadUrl("https://motorregister.skat.dk/dmr-front/appmanager/skat/dmr?_nfpb=true&_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=vis_koeretoej_side&_nfls=false");
}
```

Comment: do you have any log for 2.4.4 ?

Comment: There is no Android version 2.4.4 - do you mean 4.4.2?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes of course you are right got those numbers messed up, have edited now. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderSidikov going to find out about the log.

Comment: @AlexanderSidikov Can't get anything usefull from the logs I have access to (Genymotion and testobject) I'll try to get a user with an actual device with SDK to provide me with a log. Thing is though; when running it on a simulator like genymotion I can see the web page for maybe half a second before it disappears again and I just get a white page with 300px in the top left corner. It is like it discards all already loaded and just interpret the page as <html>..<body>300px</body></html>

Comment: maybe this could helb http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Comment: Lowering the target SDK from 19 to 18 solved the problem, but I still don't understand what exactly causes the problem.